# Being given vs giving

Tags: passive-voice, subjects

Which of the sentences is correct?

> Most people can be made happy by **being given** what they need.
>
> Most people can be made happy by **giving** what they need.

My guess is they are all correct. As for the understood subject, in the first sentence, ***being given*** take **most people** as its subject.; In the second sentence, the understood subject of "giving" is generic.

Edit: further question.

Can I interpret the second sentence as:
People can be made happy by (others) giving (to them) what they need.

Comment: The two have opposite meanings, as @BossElijah says. You could tweak the second one by saying "giving **them** what they need".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want the sentence to say, really. In the first sentence you say that they can be happy by **getting** what they need, but in the second sentence you say that they can be happy by **giving away** what they need.

My first guess is that you want the first sentence because most people aren't really happy when giving their needs away.

Comment: What if I make a little change in the second sentence: Most people can be made happy by **giving them** what they need. Does it mean the same as the first sentence, then?

Comment: @Robbyzhu yes it does giving them and being given mean the same

Comment: @WendyG They mean the same _in this context_.